# Given a matrix of size nxm, how can we calculate the sum of all possible square matrices of size (L)?

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

Given this 3x3(nxm) matrix, how can I traverse and get the sum of all possible square-submatrices i.e(1x1,2x2 in this particular case)

```
2 2 3
3 4 5
4 5 5
```

I know here,
every element is an individual submatrix(1x1),
and the rest square-submatrices are as follow:

```
2 2
3 4
```

```
2 3
4 5
```

```
3 4
4 5
```

```
4 5
5 5
```

I've tried my approach and failed multiple times, the main reason is I get confused with matrices in programming.
My Approach:
Here, 'l' is size of square-sub matrix, 'n' size of rows of main matrix, 'm' size of cols of main matrix,

```
for (i=0; i<n-l; i++){
            for (j=1; j<n-i+1; j++){
                sum = 0;
                for (p=i; p<l+i; p++){
                    for (q=1; q<l+j+1; q++){
                        sum += a[p][q];
                    }
                }
               cout << sum << endl;
            }
            l++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution of your case.

```
for(int i=0; i+(l-1)<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j+(l-1)<m; j++){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int a=0; a<l; a++){
            for(int b=0; b<l; b++){
                sum += matrix[i+a][j+b];
            }
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

or you can try to run the full code on [Tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVJBbsIwELz7Fav2AChBUGhPTngBP0A5OGYBo9iJbEelQnl76m2SEgT4YO2sZ2fHa8uqmh@lbNt3ZWRR7xESVTpvUegNY7VT5ghGaHSVkAjO7zljynjQQpnp7MogLMImXfN/oMegSFcdWCykMrDZQMFDDLWRpdYYGP6kHPgSjhjYkP@Esqr2NzXhrbrsTLbTGaTQ9aR1XcWreN3Et8Q6/oy/xokAQ6LpDBxKOyVBlS45qGhazD9miaEwmt1UB9aZWOeepSkcswZzrtbB05LfHQwSgiREEu4rHorHvJx4OfHyp7x@emXtIUmGeahIZLtzlGeUm8CEw/OpulP5HQD2dbC9bJ82oJtE6YM6fyA37LU3NPtXr/vno/cQ/kGO3qOFyuIBLRqJ7HWPQf2tm/YbxRQODdl9Wbdb9LU19DQNa9tf)

Comment: "Thank You very much"  The code is so easy to understand, now I completely get it after debugging it..

Comment: Great, now try a 10000 by 10000 matrix with 5000 by 5000 submatrices. Do you know that mankind invented multiplication to replace repeated addition of the same thing over and over again?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I don't see the relationship about repeated multiplication and addition in matrices. maybe you can share with us about that. I just want to help solve this simple case, especially about matrix indexing.

Comment: You are adding the same matrix elements over and over again. For elements far from the edges of the input matrix, you add each element L^2 times. You could replace that with one addition of `a[i][j]*L*L`. For elements close to the edges the factor would be less. It is easy to figure it out by drawing some squares.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code to make it correct, also made full example:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNboMwEIX3nGKUbkAmFW3aDTj0IAhVFtDEyDZ/posizk7HJlFcqIV4nvF8T09TtO2xEExdluWJq0KMZQX0uyp006feo8PEpem5vkq3yZtB9xXDnseVBsm48gOYPMAz6DKOVx/q3nEwTYHBGabpNQT8TnMI0ymEtxDezdWouc7JasR/qk8NCgn2bAo/CEE6FaQQwQewLMrvnRiiFba/r6YH/2YjEHxJUOh5jSgxs0LDIAFCRGCBLcQRihIUijGOCBPjQQh/jG@RekVqRKSL1Pf9uMcsbxilRXaPrmuLIzxBoRiGgDCObbBDtliHWJ2gUAx0w7r/MbtxjEJwv1mbZ12@T2T3VjSjBkrNJikcQjgY5W5R2yJeC@NpxKCVKsVf19mbvWX5BQ)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 5}};
    size_t n = a.size(), m = a.size() > 0 ? a[0].size() : 0;
    
    for (size_t l = 1; l <= std::min(n, m); ++l)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n - l + 1; ++i)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < m - l + 1; ++j) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (size_t p = i; p < i + l; ++p)
                    for (size_t q = j; q < j + l; ++q)
                        sum += a[p][q];
                std::cout << l << ", " << i << ", " << j << ": " << sum << std::endl;
            }
}
```

Input:

```
2 2 3
3 4 5
4 5 5
```

Output:

```
1, 0, 0: 2
1, 0, 1: 2
1, 0, 2: 3
1, 1, 0: 3
1, 1, 1: 4
1, 1, 2: 5
1, 2, 0: 4
1, 2, 1: 5
1, 2, 2: 5
2, 0, 0: 11
2, 0, 1: 14
2, 1, 0: 16
2, 1, 1: 19
3, 0, 0: 33
```